# Rails 4: Testing out AJAX .click and .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hi I am trying to display text from another html document with AJAX in my rails app. I just wrote this small piece of code because I'm trying to learn AJAX. Can someone please explain to me what's going wrong with this piece of code?

**Stepone.htm.erbl**

```
<div class="margin-top">
<div class="container">

<h1> Do you like Math or Science </h1>


    <br>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-4">
    <button id="math1-1"><a href="math_1"> Math </a></button>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="col-4">
<button><a href="science_1"> Science </a></button>
    </div>
</div></div></div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#math1-1").click(function(){
    $("#math1").load("math_1.html");
  });
});
</script>
```

**Math_1.html.erb**

```
<div class="margin-top">
<div class="container">

<h1> Do you like Math or Science </h1>


<br>
<div id="math1">
Math_1
</div>


</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're learning, let me give you some ideas:

---

**Ajax**

[Ajax (Asynchronous Javascript And XML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is a type of functionality inside JQuery (it's pure [XML Header Request / XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) in javascript). It basically sends a "pseudo-request" to an [endpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_endpoint) in your application, receiving & processing the response

The beauty of ajax is its *asynchronous* nature (working independently of any processes) - meaning you can use it to send a request "out of scope" of the typical application flow:

[image]

Typically used to create the appearance of providing the user with the ability to "interact" with the webpage (without it reloading), ajax has become prolific, not least due to JQuery's assimilation of the `$.ajax()` functionality into a single call

In simple terms - Ajax provides you with the ability to load & process a request on your front-end. This means if you want to use it, you need to be able to firstly have a way to process the result, and then ensure you're able to manage the response (typically by amending your `DOM`)

--

**Structure**

Since this is posted in the `Rails` section, let me give you some ideas on how to correctly get Ajax working with Rails. You need several important elements:

> 1. An endpoint
> 2. A backend controller action
> 3. A way to handle the response

You first need an [*endpoint*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_endpoint). Simply, this is a *route* which will direct your ajax request to a specific controller action. The route itself is not important (Ajax is literally just a way to send "pseudo" requests to your system). What *is* important is the action the route will lead you to:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :your_controller do
   collection do
       get :birthdays
   end
end

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :json, :html, only: :birthdays

   def birthdays
      @birthdays = Model.where(birthday: Date.today)
      respond_with @birthdays
   end 
end
```

This means that if you want to send an ajax request to the controller, you'll be able to do the following:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$.ajax({
    url: "/your_controller/birthdays",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#your_element").html(data);
    }
});
```

--

**Fix**

As mentioned by `EasyCo`, the answer for you is to make sure you have an element to append your new data to. This is relatively simple, but I also want to discuss the importance of [keeping your javascript unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) with you

You should always put your javascript into the asset pipeline of Rails (IE `/app/assets/javascripts/xxx.js`). There are many reasons for this ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), [Convention over Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)), but the most important thing is to keep your application [modular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming)

Modularity is what gives great applications a natural "flow" and structure, allowing you to use / reuse as many functions as you require throughout the app. It is for this reason why I highly recommend you include any javascript in the respective JS files - as these then act as *dependencies* for your browser-based pages

So in essence, you'll want the following:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("#math1-1").on("click", function(){
   $("#math1").get("/maths/1");
});

#app/views/maths/index.html.erb
<%= link_to "1", math_path("1") %>
<div id="math_1">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: What's the best way to store information in the database (not information that a user submits) and then pull it to specific web pages. Like let's say I wanted to store a list of questions inside the database with answers. How could I pull those using an AJAX request?

Answer (score 1):

You need a DOM element with `id="math1"` in your Stepone.html.erb file.

You're trying to load **math_1.html** but it can't find an element with ID of **math1** in **Stepone.html.erm**. It therefore doesn't load **math_1.html** because it has nowhere to append the data.

Change **Stepone.html.erb** to:

```
<div class="margin-top">
<div class="container">

<h1> Do you like Math or Science </h1>


<br>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-4">
    <button id="math1-1"><a href="math_1"> Math </a></button>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="col-4">
<button><a href="science_1"> Science </a></button>
    </div>
</div></div></div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div id="math1"></div> <!-- AJAX will get loaded in this div -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#math1-1").click(function(){
    $("#math1").load("math_1.html");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, I'm currently trying to learn AJAX and Jquery. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can. Do you know of any good resources to learn AJAX & Jquery?